# Rscript readLines() blocks until placed in background mode

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `readLines()` to get a confirmation from the user that the configuration was read correctly before running a really long batch script, and it's behaving very strangely.

Here's the test script I'm working with:

```
f = file("stdin","r");
cat("go go go\n")
invisible(readLines(f, 1))
cat("done!\n")
```

Here's what I want it to do:

```
$ Rscript test.R
go go go
[script pauses until user presses enter]
done!
$
```

Here's what it's doing instead:

```
$ Rscript test.R
go go go
[user presses enter]
[nothing happens]
[user presses ^C]
[nothing happens]
[user presses ^Z]
[1]+  Stopped                 Rscript test.R
$ bg 1
[1]+ Rscript test.R &
done!
$
```

Wat.

When I echo into stdin before the script starts, it works:

```
$ echo "\n" | Rscript test.R
go go go
done!
$
```

When I change the script to use `stdin()` instead, it perhaps predictably takes its ball and goes home, since Rscript doesn't run in interactive mode:

```
$ Rscript scripts/test.R 
go go go
$ [<-- distinct lack of 'done!']
$ echo "\n" | Rscript scripts/test.R
go go go
$ [<-- same]
```

Any ideas? My backup is just to add a big `Sys.sleep()` so the user has time to ^C if necessary, but that always feels rude.

Comment: You probably want `readLine`, not `readLines`

Comment: You need to pass `n = 1` to `readLines()` so it knows when it's done reading, since `stdin` won't have an `eof`

Comment: I'm already using n=1, and readLine isn't appropriate for this application since I need it to run in non-interactive mode. Problem persists.